# No success with retrieving from parse

Tags: android

I'm trying to read from parseObject. I have a class over there and I'm trying to get the messages from there but I get only the last message that is sent from the device.

So if I send two messages only the last one is sent.

Can anyone help me?

This is my code:

```
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("SmsTable");
            query.whereEqualTo("deviceId", android_id);
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        for (ParseObject smsObject : objects) {
                            Date time = (Date) smsObject.get("date");
                            myMsg = (String) smsObject.get("message");
                            usrNum = (String) smsObject.get("phoneNumber");
                            //happend = (boolean) smsObject.get("happend");



                                result = time;

                        }



                    } else {

                    }
                }
            });


            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= result.getTime()&& happend == false) {
                // count++;
                sendMsg2(myMsg, usrNum);
                happend = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
for (ParseObject smsObject : objects) {
   Date time = (Date) smsObject.get("date");
   myMsg = (String) smsObject.get("message");
   usrNum = (String) smsObject.get("phoneNumber");
   //happend = (boolean) smsObject.get("happend");
   result = time;

   if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= result.getTime()&& happend == false) {
       // count++;
       sendMsg2(myMsg, usrNum);
       happend = true;
    }
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `myMsg` and `usrNum` are not an Array or a List.

You only call `sendMsg2(myMsg, usrNum)` once, after the loop has ended. That is why you only get the last message.

Move `sendMsg2(myMsg, usrNum)` into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you have located your sendMsg2() outside of both - the callback scope and the loop scope. If you want to have all of your messages being sent you have to put sendMsg2() inside of the loop.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("SmsTable");
        query.whereEqualTo("deviceId", android_id);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (ParseObject smsObject : objects) {
                        Date time = (Date) smsObject.get("date");
                        myMsg = (String) smsObject.get("message");
                        usrNum = (String) smsObject.get("phoneNumber");
                        //happend = (boolean) smsObject.get("happend");

                            result = time;

                       if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= result.getTime()&&        happend == false) {
                          // count++;
                          sendMsg2(myMsg, usrNum);
                          happend = true;
                       }
                    }
                } else {

                }
            }
        });
```